# Firebase ServerValue.increment(1) doesnt work on cloud functions

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-admin

I'm trying to use the increment feature on the firebase admin sdk for node.js.
My function is deployed to cloud functions node version 10

here is the code

```
let admin = require('firebase-admin').initializeApp({
    databaseURL: "https://igibo-b0b27.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "igibo-b0b27"
});

const igDatabase = admin.database();

exports.test = (req, res) => {

igDatabase.ref('test123').set(admin.database.ServerValue.increment(1));
res.status(200).send('ok');
};
```

here is the package.json

```
{
  "name": "authenticate",
  "version": "1.0.0",
   "dependencies": {
 
     "firebase-admin": "^9.1.1"
   }
}
```

but when i try to call the function i get `TypeError: Cannot read property 'increment' of undefined`

what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you're declaring `admin` isn't right for use with ServerValue.  Use this instead:

```
let admin = require('firebase-admin')

admin.initializeApp({
    databaseURL: "https://igibo-b0b27.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "igibo-b0b27"
});

const igDatabase = admin.database();

exports.test = (req, res) => {
    igDatabase.ref('test123').set(admin.database.ServerValue.increment(1))
    .then(() => { res.status(200).send('ok'); })
};
```

Also note that I added `then` to the call to `set()` because it's asynchronous and returns a promise.  You need to use that promise to wait for the write to complete before sending the response.